# is there a way to include the org id in the S3 bucket policy

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have a bucket policy. Snippet below. I would like to use org id instead of putting all the account ids of a org. is that possible?

```
"Sid": "Stmt458754545842",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "ssm.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::cgna.inventory.resource.data.sync/*/accountid=123456789120/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::cgna.inventory.resource.data.sync/*/accountid=123145789415/*"
```

Comment: This policy is authorizing SSM to store objects in a given path. I presume SSM always stores the objects in a path that includes the Account ID. Therefore, changing the bucket policy won't change the behaviour of SSM. In reading [Configuring Resource Data Sync for Inventory - AWS Systems Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-inventory-datasync.html) I could not see an option to change the name of the output files, but there is an example of a policy for AWS Organizations (at the very end) that uses wildcards to simply the policy.

Comment: thank you. I thought I tried this earlier and it didn't work. But it worked this time. Thank you very much.